# How to test my OpenGL code on different OpenGL versions but on one PC?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

Is there any way to test my OpenGL code on different OpenGL versions but on one PC?

For example, any virtual machine, where I can choose what OpenGL version I want to have there?

I want to check how my app will work with OpenGL 2.0, 3.0, 3.3, 4.0, and 4.5+.
My current graphic card support the newest OpenGL version.

Comment: This is not quite how OpenGL versions work. You have one graphics card driver that hosts a single OpenGL implementation (two if you count EGL), and the version you request in your application just limits what API calls are valid to make. If that is all you want to test, you can just play around with your OpenGL context selection and request a core file of the appropriate version.

Comment: To be more precise, I would like to check if, for example, my application crashes or works properly on version 2.0. So I can't check it so easily on my computer. Of course, I know that I can check whether specific API functions are correctly loaded or not. But that still doesn't give me 100% certainty that I'm not doing something wrong. So I wanted to somehow run maybe a virtual machine or something where this version could be limited.

Comment: The difference between versions of OpenGL is mostly making certain extensions part of the core and deprecating some functions. At the end of the day it's still going to the same single OpenGL driver, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Raffallo 100% certainty is unachievable in this world; to be more confident that your code works on other systems, test it on those other systems. Drivers may allow behaviors that aren't part of the OpenGL spec, and if your code happens to rely on those then it may fail with a different driver on a different machine.

Comment: OpenGL API changes are expressed in [official docs](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/index_gl.php). You may check each and every gl-command you use... if you feel brave enough.

Comment: What did you plan if, for example, OGL 3.3 is available, but 4.0 is not? Will you write code for each version? What would you achieve?

Comment: Be aware of that same code, with same OGL version, may work in a machine but not in another, or not until they fix some bug. Welcome to vendors' nightmare!

Comment: *Everyone* who's going to run your program in 2023 has OpenGL 4.6.

Comment: @user253751 I wish it was like that, but unfortunately it's not in my case :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your program against [Mesa's software renderer](https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/llvmpipe.html) and experiment with the [`MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE`](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html#envvar-MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE) environment variable:

> changes the value returned by `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and possibly the GL API type.

Combine with [`MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE`](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html#envvar-MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE) to provide [a matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Versions) GLSL version:

> changes the value returned by `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)`. Valid values are integers, such as 130...

And finally [`MESA_EXTENSION_MAX_YEAR`](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html#envvar-MESA_EXTENSION_MAX_YEAR) can limit which extensions are exposed:

> The `GL_EXTENSIONS` string returned by Mesa is sorted by extension year. If this variable is set to year X, only extensions defined on or before year X will be reported.